# Reduce opacity of non focused items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list of items which are displayed on the home screen, the list is vertically scrollable. At the moment I have 5 items but items are added as the user approaches the last item creating an infinite scroll.

I want to have all the items faded out but the one in focus should be fully trasparent like so:

[image]

As you can see the item to the left and right are faded and are a little smaller whilst the item in focus is fully transparent and is slightly bigger indicating that this is the item in focus.

This is my `Composable` list:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreenList() {
    val homeScreenItems = getItems()
    val listState = rememberLazyListState(Int.MAX_VALUE / 2)
    LazyRow(
        state = listState,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
    ) {
        items(Int.MAX_VALUE, itemContent = {
            val index = it % homeScreenItems.size
            HomeScreenItem(model = homeScreenItems[index])
        })
    }
}
```

And the `HomeScreenItem`:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreenItem(model: HomeScreenViewModel) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 20.dp),
        elevation = 2.dp,
        backgroundColor = model.mBackgroundColor,
        shape = Shapes.large,
    ) {
        Row {
             Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = model.mIcon),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(20.dp)
            .size(100.dp)
    )
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I should achieve this?

Comment: Can you update project  to the github and share it, I can help.

Comment: sorry I'will be busy for some days, but you can refer this post https://medium.com/@Rieger_san/create-a-chipgroup-with-jetpack-compose-f4744b94fa34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the list state to determine how far away each item is from the center, and apply opacity accordingly:

```kotlin
val homeScreenItems = remember {
    listOf(
        Icons.Default.Person,
        Icons.Default.Usb,
        Icons.Default.Keyboard,
    )
}
val listState = rememberLazyListState(Int.MAX_VALUE / 2)
val (rowHalfSize, setRowHalfSize) = remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }
val horizontalContentPadding = 16.dp
val density = LocalDensity.current
LazyRow(
    state = listState,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = horizontalContentPadding, vertical = 8.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .onSizeChanged {
            setRowHalfSize(it.width / 2 - with(density) { horizontalContentPadding.roundToPx() })
        }
) {
    items(Int.MAX_VALUE) { globalIndex ->
        val index = globalIndex % homeScreenItems.size
        val opacity by remember(rowHalfSize) {
            derivedStateOf {
                if (rowHalfSize == null) return@derivedStateOf 0.5f
                val currentItemInfo = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
                    .firstOrNull() { it.index == globalIndex }
                    ?: return@derivedStateOf 0.5f
                val itemHalfSize = currentItemInfo.size / 2
                (1f - minOf(1f, abs(currentItemInfo.offset + itemHalfSize - rowHalfSize).toFloat() / itemHalfSize) * 0.5f)
            }
        }
        Icon(
            homeScreenItems[index], null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .alpha(opacity)
                .scale(opacity)
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

add `isFocused` param for `HomeScreenItem` to handle its state.

Now handle this param based on some condition, when that particular item will get in focus.

Condition to get the item in focus:

```kotlin
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
val focusableIndex = scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex + scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.size/2
```

or have some custom logic to do that.

Comment: @KTOV can you update the title and problem description more clearly.