# How to create dot indicator (with color and size transiton) in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, android-jetpack-compose, viewpagerindicator

I want to have a horizontal dot indicator that has color transition between two dots that is scrolling and also dot's size transition while scrolling

I need to show only limited dots for a huge amount of items.

[image]

In view system, we used this library https://github.com/Tinkoff/ScrollingPagerIndicator, which is very smooth and has a very nice color and size transition effects.

I tried to implement it with scroll state `rememberLazyListState()`, but it is more complex than I thought.

Do you know any solution in Jetpack Compose?

Is it possible to use the current library with AndroidView? Because it needs XML view, recycler view and viewpager, I am wondering how is it possible to use it with AndroidView?

Comment: Accompanist library has pagers with indicators - [look here](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/). And [here](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/pager/HorizontalPagerWithIndicatorSample.kt) is example of usage.

Comment: I haven't worked with `ScrollingPagerIndicator` so I don't know whether it's possible to use it in compose without recycler view. I'd build such element by myself, but I don't have time to do it for you right now.

Comment: Check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71305461/3585796), it's animating the items itself, but the logic can be applied to your case

Comment: @Pylyp Dukhov thanks for your answer, but it deosn't help, I need to show only limited dots for a huge amount of items.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I have the same need.

Comment: @MayNotBe yes, I integrated it in android view, I will write it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could integrate this library https://github.com/Tinkoff/ScrollingPagerIndicator easily with compose.

```
@Composable
fun DotIndicator(scrollState: LazyListState, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    AndroidViewBinding(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = DotIndicatorBinding::inflate,
    ) {
        dotIndicator.setDotCount(scrollState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount)
        dotIndicator.setCurrentPosition(scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex)
        scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull()?.size?.let { firstItemSize ->
            val firstItemOffset = scrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            val offset = (firstItemOffset.toFloat() / firstItemSize.toFloat()).coerceIn(0f, 1f)
            dotIndicator.onPageScrolled(scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex, offset)
        }
    }
}
```

For the integration I had to add XML file as well ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data />

    <ru.tinkoff.scrollingpagerindicator.ScrollingPagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/dot_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:spi_dotColor="@color/ds_primary_25"
        app:spi_dotSelectedColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:spi_dotSelectedSize="8dp"
        app:spi_dotSize="8dp"
        app:spi_dotSpacing="4dp" />

</layout>
```

And also adding this dependency to your Gradle file ->

```
api "androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding:1.1.1"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  I ended up building [one](https://gist.github.com/kliphouse/a139f27bbdebf5187dd3c3a840925495) based on [this library](https://github.com/wching/Android-Indefinite-Pager-Indicator).  I'm planning to make a PR when I have a minute.

Answer (score 9):

I made a sample looks similar, logic for scaling is raw but it looks similar.

[image]

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun PagerIndicator(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    pagerState: PagerState,
    indicatorCount: Int = 5,
    indicatorSize: Dp = 16.dp,
    indicatorShape: Shape = CircleShape,
    space: Dp = 8.dp,
    activeColor: Color = Color(0xffEC407A),
    inActiveColor: Color = Color.LightGray,
    orientation: IndicatorOrientation = IndicatorOrientation.Horizontal,
    onClick: ((Int) -> Unit)? = null
) {

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    val totalWidth: Dp = indicatorSize * indicatorCount + space * (indicatorCount - 1)
    val widthInPx = LocalDensity.current.run { indicatorSize.toPx() }

    val currentItem by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            pagerState.currentPage
        }
    }

    val itemCount = pagerState.pageCount

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = currentItem) {
        val viewportSize = listState.layoutInfo.viewportSize
        if (orientation == IndicatorOrientation.Horizontal) {
            listState.animateScrollToItem(
                currentItem,
                (widthInPx / 2 - viewportSize.width / 2).toInt()
            )
        } else {
            listState.animateScrollToItem(
                currentItem,
                (widthInPx / 2 - viewportSize.height / 2).toInt()
            )
        }

    }

    if (orientation == IndicatorOrientation.Horizontal) {
        LazyRow(
            modifier = modifier.width(totalWidth),
            state = listState,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = space),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space),
            userScrollEnabled = false
        ) {
            indicatorItems(
                itemCount,
                currentItem,
                indicatorCount,
                indicatorShape,
                activeColor,
                inActiveColor,
                indicatorSize,
                onClick
            )
        }
    } else {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = modifier.height(totalWidth),
            state = listState,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = space),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space),
            userScrollEnabled = false
        ) {
            indicatorItems(
                itemCount,
                currentItem,
                indicatorCount,
                indicatorShape,
                activeColor,
                inActiveColor,
                indicatorSize,
                onClick
            )
        }
    }

}

private fun LazyListScope.indicatorItems(
    itemCount: Int,
    currentItem: Int,
    indicatorCount: Int,
    indicatorShape: Shape,
    activeColor: Color,
    inActiveColor: Color,
    indicatorSize: Dp,
    onClick: ((Int) -> Unit)?
) {
    items(itemCount) { index ->

        val isSelected = (index == currentItem)

        // Index of item in center when odd number of indicators are set
        // for 5 indicators this is 2nd indicator place
        val centerItemIndex = indicatorCount / 2

        val right1 =
            (currentItem < centerItemIndex &&
                    index >= indicatorCount - 1)

        val right2 =
            (currentItem >= centerItemIndex &&
                    index >= currentItem + centerItemIndex &&
                    index < itemCount - centerItemIndex + 1)
        val isRightEdgeItem = right1 || right2

        // Check if this item's distance to center item is smaller than half size of
        // the indicator count when current indicator at the center or
        // when we reach the end of list. End of the list only one item is on edge
        // with 10 items and 7 indicators
        // 7-3= 4th item can be the first valid left edge item and
        val isLeftEdgeItem =
            index <= currentItem - centerItemIndex &&
                    currentItem > centerItemIndex &&
                    index < itemCount - indicatorCount + 1

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .graphicsLayer {
                    val scale = if (isSelected) {
                        1f
                    } else if (isLeftEdgeItem || isRightEdgeItem) {
                        .5f
                    } else {
                        .8f
                    }
                    scaleX = scale
                    scaleY = scale

                }

                .clip(indicatorShape)
                .size(indicatorSize)
                .background(
                    if (isSelected) activeColor else inActiveColor,
                    indicatorShape
                )
                .then(
                    if (onClick != null) {
                        Modifier
                            .clickable {
                                onClick.invoke(index)
                            }
                    } else Modifier
                )
        )
    }
}

enum class IndicatorOrientation {
    Horizontal, Vertical
}
```

Usage

```
@Composable
private fun PagerIndicatorSample() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Spacer(Modifier.height(40.dp))
        val pagerState1 = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        PagerIndicator(pagerState = pagerState1) {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                pagerState1.scrollToPage(it)
            }
        }

        HorizontalPager(
            count = 10,
            state = pagerState1,
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .shadow(1.dp, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    "Text $it",
                    fontSize = 40.sp,
                    color = Color.Gray
                )
            }
        }

        val pagerState2 = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)

        PagerIndicator(
            pagerState = pagerState2,
            indicatorSize = 24.dp,
            indicatorCount = 7,
            activeColor = Color(0xffFFC107),
            inActiveColor = Color(0xffFFECB3),
            indicatorShape = CutCornerShape(10.dp)
        )
        HorizontalPager(
            count = 10,
            state = pagerState2,
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .shadow(1.dp, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    "Text $it",
                    fontSize = 40.sp,
                    color = Color.Gray
                )
            }
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            val pagerState3 = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))

            PagerIndicator(
                pagerState = pagerState3,
                orientation = IndicatorOrientation.Vertical
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(20.dp))
            VerticalPager(
                count = 10,
                state = pagerState3,
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(10.dp)
                        .shadow(1.dp, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(200.dp),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        "Text $it",
                        fontSize = 40.sp,
                        color = Color.Gray
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Need to convert from

```
listState.animateScrollToItem()
```

to

```
listState.animateScrollBy()
```

for smooth indicator change and moving with offset change from Pager.

and do some more methodical scale and color and offset calculating this one is only a temporary solution.

Comment: Thanks for your effort , I did it as well but it is not comparable with the library, it doesn't have any smooth animation. tbh, the hard part is the smooth transition of the color and size which is complex.

Comment: It was not much of an effort i did this for the guy that linked to this post. If animation is what you desire i  will add it when i'm done with image cropper i'm working on. Changing size and color is not complex. Compose only lacks ColorEvaluator which can be done with Android counterpart

Comment: It would be great, if you can do it.  It needs many calculations for transition color and size, it doesn't use any animation.
Just this smooth color transition and resizing looks like a very nice animation.
Looking forward to see the result @Thracian

Comment: If we use this   val listState = rememberLazyListState() inside a lazyCoulmn then it crashes(if you scroll inside the dotIndicator and then scrolls down) I think it crashes because it mixes the scroll position between to diffrent list 
Do you know how is it possible to fix it?
Thank you very much

Comment: I will look into it this weekend. I actually built animating items when scrolled but it's for another library. I'm not available  at the moment but it might give you the idea about how to animate. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-AnimatedList.

Comment: @SepidehVatankhah would you mind opening an issue for pager library here with crash log and more detail, sorry, i'm not able to understand why it happens especially with further information. Thanks in advance, happy coding. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-PagerIndicator

Comment: Thank you very much. I used this in my uni project. It was very helpful and saved a lot of time.

Comment: I noticed an issue with this implementation for some edge cases. Sometimes, `listState.layoutInfo.viewportSize` does not have the correct values yet (the size is 0x0).

To fix this, derive the state from the actual viewportSize: `val viewportSize by remember { derivedStateOf { listState.layoutInfo.viewportSize } }`.

Then, you can just add it as key to the LaunchedEffect: `LaunchedEffect(currentItem, viewportSize) { ... }`.